# Capture specific row information after calling blur event

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

Let's say that I have this table with two rows:

```
<tr>
    <td contenteditable="true" data-group1="<?php echo $_GET['group']; ?>" class="no1" id="nom1" name="nom1"><?php echo $item[$i]; ?></td>
</tr>

<tr>
    <td contenteditable="true" data-group2="<?php echo $_GET['group']; ?>" class="no2" id="nom2" name="nom2"><?php echo $item[$i]; ?></td>
</tr>
```

The table is contenteditable which means, I can change the value inside the table. Currently, once the data have been manipulated, the data will be captured once the blur event is called. This is my script:

```
$(document).on('blur', '.no1', function(){
    var group= $(this).data("group1");
    var no = $(this).text();
});

$(document).on('blur', '.no2', function(){
    var group= $(this).data("group2");
    var no = $(this).text();
});
```

Based on this algorithm, let's say that I have manipulated the data from the first row which is referring to the `class = "no1"`, it will then run this script as shown above:

```
$(document).on('blur', '.no1', function(){
    var group= $(this).data("group1");
    var no = $(this).text();
});
```

However, the number of rows for this table is not fixed. Therefore, this script is not helpful as we defined the function by ourselves based on the number of rows. Is there any way on how we can capture specific row information after calling the blur event so that we do not have to define quite a lot of similar functions.

Comment: Why are the custom data attributes “numbered” in the first place? If you didn’t do that, you would not have this problem to begin with, right?

Answer (score 1):

You can use a common class on your `trs` and attach a `blur` event handler on its `contenteditable td`.

About your `data-groupX` attributes, just rename them all to `data-group` :

> PHP

```
<tr class="common"> //Add your class here
<td contenteditable="true" data-group="<?php echo $_GET['group']; ?>" class="no1" id="nom1" name="nom1"><?php echo $item[$i]; ?></td>
</tr>
```

> Javascript

```
$(document).on('blur', '.common td[contenteditable]', function(){
  var group= $(this).data("group");
  var no = $(this).text();
});
```